# how to add log when call http request in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I need to add log after call http request in big project like this?

```
$response = Http::get('http://example.com');
Log::info(`add request and header and response`);
```

i want to define global log for all http requests.

i need to define macro like this :

```
 \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::macro('log',function(){
    Log::info(`add request and header and response`);
  });
```

and call http request like this:

```
 $response = Http::get('http://example.com')->log();
```

Answer (score 2):

Http is built on Guzzle, which accepts cURL options. One of those is CURLOPT_VERBOSE, rewritten as `debug`, which will send request data to either the screen or a log file. It accepts a file resource as an option:

```
$response = Http::withOptions(['debug'=>true])->get('http://example.com');
```

Or

```
$fp = fopen(storage_path('http_log.txt'), 'w+');
$response = Http::withOptions(['debug'=>$fp])->get('http://example.com');
```

If you need more data than that, you can extend the Http class and add your own logging methods to it.

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#guzzle-options and https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#debug for information on the debug option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Terminable Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#terminable-middleware) to log the HTTP response after it has already been sent to the browser.

To get the total time you can compare the result of `microtime(true)` with the laravel constant `LARAVEL_START`. That constant is defined at `bootstrap/autoload.php`, the entry point of the framework

For instance, here is a middleware that will log in both HTTP headers and system log the response time. Since you have access to the current request in the `$request` variable you could leverage that to also log any parameters you want

```
<?php // File: app/Http/Middleware/MeasureResponseTime.php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MeasureResponseTime
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming HTTP request.
     *
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        // Add response time as an HTTP header. For better accuracy ensure this middleware
        // is added at the end of the list of global middlewares in the Kernel.php file
        if (defined('LARAVEL_START') and $response instanceof Response) {
            $response->headers->add(['X-RESPONSE-TIME' => microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START]);
        }

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Perform any final actions for the request lifecycle.
     *
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response $response
     * @return void
     */
    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
        // At this point the response has already been sent to the browser so any
        // modification to the response (such adding HTTP headers) will have no effect
        if (defined('LARAVEL_START') and $request instanceof Request) {
            app('log')->debug('Response time', [
                'method' => $request->getMethod(),
                'uri' => $request->getRequestUri(),
                'seconds' => microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is for request not http client request. `https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client`